# ios facebook login , email not returning for some facebook accounts

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using **pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'**  for facebook login in my app. I need the user's  **id ,name and email**. This is the code I am using for fetching the data.

```
- (IBAction)btnFacebookPressed:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
                 [self fetchUserInfo];
                 [login logOut]; // Only If you don't want to save the session for current app
             }
         }
     }];
}
-(void)fetchUserInfo
{
    if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]hasGranted:@"email"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);

        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);

             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
             }
         }];
    }else{
        [self btnFacebookPressed:nil];
    }
}
```

I am not able to get email  most of my friend's facebook signin.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you do get the email for some accounts, but not for all of them, it can have 2 reasons:

- Your friends denied the email permission
- Their email address is not confirmed or they have used their phone to login - i believe that is possible instead of an email

Comment: thanks  @luschn  ,  its  a verified email Address  and  i am Login with the Email Address.

Comment: so it´s about YOUR account? i though it is working for some users, but for some it isn´t?